# offline speech recognition in my android app

Tags: speech-to-text

i am trying to use google offline speech recognition  in my android app which just converts speech into text but its not working. i have downloaded offline language . the same app works fine with internet connection on but doesn't work in offline mode the main code is as follows:

MAIN CODE

```js
package com.example.parth.texttospeech;

import android.content.ActivityNotFoundException;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.speech.RecognizerIntent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Locale;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    TextView resultTEXT;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
    public void onButtonClick(View v)
    {
        if(v.getId()==R.id.bttexttospeech)
        {
            resultTEXT=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvresult);
            prompSpeechInput();
        }
    }
    public void prompSpeechInput()
    {
        Intent i=new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
       i.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
        i.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,Locale.getDefault());
        i.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT,"say something");
        try{
            startActivityForResult(i,100);

        }catch(ActivityNotFoundException e)
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"sorry device doesnt support text to speech",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    public void onActivityResult(int request_code, int result_code, Intent i) {
        super.onActivityResult(request_code,result_code,i);
        {
            switch(request_code)
            {
                case 100:if(result_code==RESULT_OK && i!=null)
                {
                    ArrayList<String> result=i.getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
                    resultTEXT.setText(result.get(0));
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

To work in the offline mode, the language package must be there. Download and update all the packages.

Moreover, you might wanna add  intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_MAX_RESULTS, 15); in your code.